# jquery slim adding only ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to work on an esp8266, so I first worked with jquery slim and used a python program to minify and convert the script into a hex string for serving.

Unfortunately, jquery slim does not include ajax. I thought I could simply use the normal version of jquery, but it fails the minification.

Before I pull my hair with vanilla js, I wondered if there were a standalone ajax module I could try to minify.

(I can't really share a minimum working example, my question only regards the existence of the module)

Comment: There is already a minified version of jQuery: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js. Why can't you use that?

Comment: [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) is pretty easy to use.